# How do I automate Phone verification (need codes sent to mobile)?

Tags: android, verification, smartphone, browser-automation, webautomation

[Background]

I am looking for some way to automate phone verification (6 digit code sent on cell phones(android) )

[My Way-probably really lame]

Create an app that polls messages coming in, search for keyword "verification".

If found ,get the 6 digit number from the message and update the file over network from cell.
Script on PC will read entry of file after the verification code was sent and use it.

Are there any API's exposed?
Verification is similar to what we have on gmail.
Thanks in advance for any inputs

Comment: Please clarify... it's difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve (at least for me ;-) )

Comment: I am automating a web page login. It sends 6 verification code to my Android handset. Trying to figure out a way so that I have the verification code on my machine

Comment: Okay, why the down vote?? Please help understand.

Comment: It is still unclear. Where the message (with 6 digits) comes from ? What's the difference between "PC" and "my machine" ? Is there an application server in this story (and what is his role) ? message is sent by sms ? (and in this case how do you know the phone number ?)  (additionnaly, I'm pretty sure that "verification on gmail" is not the same in all countries and/or for all users) (and the concept of "login automation" is also unclear) ("web page login" ... on an android phone, on standard PC, does it make any difference ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Sync Messages to another Gmail acocunt where such login is not required.
2. Create an Console app that reads you gmail folders
3. poll for latest message, and voila, you have your code.